# Clip_Management seems to delete shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, shapefile, clip, analysis

We have some python code that clips a very large shapefile for further processing.

We can see the process create all the output files, but then just as the process is finishing, they get deleted.

The only files left over are SBN, SBX, and XML files. What the heck is going on?

We can run the process just fine within ArcMap, but the python code seems to be messing something up.

Here's the code:

```
# Check out any necessary licenses
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")

Sage4ac = "D:\\DPerret\\GIS\\Base_Data\\SagebrushData\\SageLeks\\Sagebursh.gdb\\Poly\\Sage4ac"

# Process: Clip Sage
arcpy.Clip_analysis(aoi, Sage4ac, tempPath + "sageclip.shp", "")
```

Comment: Would you be able to confirm, by using Copy As Python Snippet, that you are using precisely the same inputs and outputs when this works in ArcMap and appears not to from ArcPy, please?  My suspicion is that Clip is bailing when the shapefile it tries to write hits the 2Gb size limit.

Comment: Thanks for the thought. The shapefile before clipping is just over 2Gb, and the clipped file is much smaller than that. Inputs and outputs are identical.

Comment: Well, we got it to work. Just pulled the original shapefile out of the geodatabase, and for some reason it ran through just fine.

Comment: If you're using shapefiles that are at or around the shapefile size limit, consider performing storage and processing within a geodatabase, as this has a much higher size limit.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that Clip is bailing when the shapefile it tries to write hits the 2Gb size limit.

It would be good to confirm, by using Copy As Python Snippet, that you are using precisely the same inputs and outputs when this works in ArcMap and appears not to from ArcPy.